# Programs take a long time to open, but only after a trigger I can't figure out. Been trying to fix this for months

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10
Asus Tuf gaming x570 plus (wifi), most recent BIOS firmware (4002)
Ryzen 5600x
RTX 2060 (most recent driver)
DDR4 3600mhz
NVMe Samsung 970 Evo (system drive)

A few months ago programs started to take varying amounts of time, as much as 30 seconds, maybe more, to start opening. Mostly games do this, but also emulators. This only starts after some time of the PC being on. I have tried to figure out what causes it to start for months. I cannot figure it out no matter what I do. Almost everything else opens normally at all times. I looked at resource monitor to compare and there is nothing different between the times when everything is opening instantly as they should, and when they suddenly start taking a long time. All I can see if that they just sit there in list of things in memory, but seemingly not loading into memory, as they normally do almost instantly. They suddenly start loading into memory after that waiting time I mentioned at the beginning on the post.

Like I said, this only happens after a trigger that I can't figure out. It's sometimes days after booting, usually hours, and rarely in minutes but still happens.
It happens regardless of whether a program is loading from my NVMe drive, or my sata SSD.

I've tried everything short of replacing hardware. Temps make no difference and everything works perfectly until it doesn't, so I assume it is not a hardware problem, but it could be, I'm no expert after all. Even reinstalling Windows 10 after reformatting my drive didn't help.
Turned off all Windows security features, made no difference. I tried increasing page file size, and disabling it entirely. No difference. I tried updating drivers all over the place, and reinstalling them, no difference. I tried reseating my RAM and GPU today, no difference. I tried chaning all sorts of BIOS options, and using the default options when I updated the firmware. Guess what? No difference. I may have tried other things, I can't remember what off the top of my head, but none of it ever made any difference at all.

Oh I just remembered, today I tried opening a bunch of programs and websites one after the other after restarting to see if its triggered by simply opening things. It did cause it after a couple minutes surprisingly. This was only way I could ever trigger it. But it also happened once almost right after restarting without doing anything.
I also did a test with 2 different emulators (because they are easiest to test) Dolphin and Ryujinx. Dolphin took 10 seconds to open (normally instant). Ryujinx took 30 seconds to open. Another weird thing is that this problem also causes dolphin to take another 20 seconds to close (normally instant). Very very weird. Everything else closes instantly.

This whole thing is the strangest most impossible to solve problem I have ever had with my PC. I've never had an issue that carried over to a new Windows install like this, while also not seeming like a hardware issue, while also totally seeming like a hardware issue at the same time.

Extra thoughts: I thought it was caused by Windows update at first, but now I don't know. It started around the same time as a bluetooth issue that is seemingly unrelated, but who knows. Bluetooth controllers used to work fine with minimal latency, with 2 controllers at once. Now, latency is increased, and jumps up a lot randomly when using 2 at once. After typing this all out, it feels hopeless and realize I may just need new hardware. But which hardware is the question.... I just bought this motherboard 7 months ago.

Good god someone help it's driving me nuts

Comment: try experiments to see if any effect on the problem: Disable antivirus/windows defender. Create a new windows user account and run programs under it. Disconnect from internet/network. Lastly try reinstalling windows on new HDD and see if any change. Also look in windows event viewer to see if anything obvious. In resource monitor in disk tab>storage>is active time near 100% for any drive? In the memory tab at the bottom under physical memory is the memory near 100% full?

Comment: Open *Task Manager* when it happens. Goto *Details* tab and sort on *CPU* and *Memory (Active Private Working Set)*. What are the top few and their measurements in each column.

Comment: I've tried most of that already. Ill try the rest but if anyone sees this, just assume it didn't work if I don't make an update saying it did.

Comment: I bought a new SSD yesterday as well. 870 evo. That made no differene. I noticed it starts after a sufficient amount of either memory activity, disk activity, or both, or just general usage of the PC. It I have torrents seeding, it starts happening faster than if I don't for instance. If I open up a ton of websites after booting, it happens quicker. Not leaving them open or anything like that. Just opening them at all.  Watching what happens in resource monitor or task manager shows that things just sit in memory, slowly increasing, then suddenly loading like normal after some seconds, ~10-60

Comment: New user account makes no difference

Comment: So you won't answer comments that ask you for further information. You will only consider guesses based on no information.

Comment: Your PC seems to have alot going on. Try removing all none necessary hardware (run only a single stick of RAM, remove as many USB devices as possible, ...). Try your hand at creating a USB stick with a live linux environment on it and run that to see if the same strange behaviour pops up. Have you checked SSD speeds once your PC starts exhibiting this slow down ?

Comment: Sorry  user1292580. I forgot to say, those top things are the program I am opening at the time, and searchapp and defender. But turning them off makes little difference. I don't think they are the problem. 

Silbee: I can try that

Comment: I have checked SSD speeds after and all is good. Things load at the proper speed once the weird delay is over. I know I sais it loads really slow at first, the thing is that, it's so slow at first it's pretty much the same as though it isn't loading at all. Then bam, starts loading like nothing was wrong.
BTW peeps, I am really good at searching google for solutions to problems, but I am terrible at asking for help myself. So forgive my not answering some things as it's overwhelming me a tad and I don't even notice I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I see ASUS in your hardware list. ASUS (as well as Lenovo) ships/installs Sonic Studio as a sound system control. The Nahimic service, the core of Sonic Studio, is what is causing your IO bottleneck. You should be able to use Process Monitor from SysInternals to confirm this when you try launching a program. Either disable the Nahimic service or completely uninstall Sonic Studio from your system. Disabling doesn't kill your sound, you just lose the fine controls/EQ/etc. that it provides, nor will Sonic Studio launch while this service is disabled.

Comment: Interesting thanks for that.  This problem stopped at some point and I didn't even notice. Thank god honestly it was annoying as hell. I don't recall ever seeing sonic studio on my PC but it's possible I didn't notice, or just don't remember.  Anyway thanks good to know anyway